# How i can make custom validators in adonis /node.js?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

Actually i have one function `store(){}` in my controller that make several validations, this validations return response status specific, i'm thinking if exist one way that i can import this validations and test before the `create()` method.

Actually my code is:

```
async store ({ request, response }) {

    const qt_options_menor_0 = this.verificaOptionsMenor0(request.body.qt_options)
    if(qt_options_menor_0){
      return response
      .status(406)
      .json({ message: "Não é possível cadastrar quantidade de opções menor que 0" });
    }

    const qt_options_igual_0 = this.verificaOptionsIgual0(request.body.qt_options)
    if(qt_options_igual_0)
      return response
      .status(406)
      .json({ message: "Não é possível cadastrar quantidade de opções igual a 0" });

 const parameter = {
      ...request.all(),
      user_id: request.user_id
    }
    const parametroCriado = await Parameter.create(parameter)
    return parametroCriado
  }

       verificaQtQuizSendIgual0(qt_quiz_send){
    if(qt_quiz_send === 0){
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }
  }

  verificaOptionsMenor0(qt_options){
    if(qt_options < 0){
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }
  }
```

This way my controller have much code, there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Adonis validator](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/validator)

Like:

*Validator file*

```js
'use strict'

class Option {
  get rules() {
    return {
      // Your rules
    }
  }

  get messages() {
    var antl = this.ctx.antl;
    return {
       // Custom messages
    }
  }

  async fails(errorMessages) {
    return this.ctx.response.status(406).json({ message: "Não é possível cadastrar quantidade de opções menor que 0" });
  }
}

module.exports = Option
```

*Command*

```sh
> adonis make:validator Option
```

*Use validator - `start/route.js`*

```js
...
Route
  ...
  .validator('Option')
```

Comment: When i use: .validator('MyValidator') i'm receiving: "Unresolved function or method validator() do you know something about this?

Comment: This is my code: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/643407991155982336/654404772815831052/unknown.png

Comment: Hi, (I have no idea if this is going to work) try to put `validator` before `middleware`